# MFC CAsyncSocket OnCloseが発生しない

Tags: mfc

お世話になります。
サーバと複数クライアントの接続構成で
MFCでソケット通信を作成しております

サーバ(Listen側)がクライアント(Connect側)からのOnCloseで
ソケット通信を終了しているのですが
たまにOnCloseコールバックが発生しない場合があります

考えられる原因などありましたら
ご教授頂けますでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

相手側が[`CAsyncSocket::ShutDown`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/cpp/mfc/reference/casyncsocket-class?view=vs-2019#shutdown)を呼び出し、その内容が正しく受信できて初めて[`CAsyncSocket::OnClose`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/cpp/mfc/reference/casyncsocket-class?view=vs-2019#onclose)が発生するため、呼び出していなかったり、呼び出し終わる前に閉じられてしまったり、通信障害で送信されなかったり、様々な原因が考えられます。

Keep-Aliveを行うことで、相手側の不在を検出する手が使えるかもしれません。

Comment: ありがとうございます！Keep-Aliveですね。試してみます